# Why Is virtual keyword "persistent" throughout a hierarchy in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have a function print() in 3 classes A, B, and C.
C inherits from B inherits from A.
Keyword virtual is only used in A.

Why does both of the following use the print() in C?

```
    A* ac = new C();
    ac->print(); //C's print() 

    B* bc = new C();
    bc->print(); //C's print(), not B's print() even though virtual is not used.
```

What is the intuition here?

Full working code below if you want to compile/run it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(){
        cout << "construct A" << endl;
    }
    virtual void print(){
        cout << "A says" << endl;
    }
};


class B: public A{
public:    
    B(){
        cout << "construct B" << endl;
    }
    void print(){
        cout << "B says" << endl;
    }    
};

class C: public B{
public:    
    C(){
        cout << "construct C" << endl;
    }
    void print(){
        cout << "C says" << endl;
    }    
    void print(int x){
        cout << "C says " << x << endl;
    }
};


int main(){

    A* ac = new C();
    ac->print();

    B* bc = new C();
    bc->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oops typo. I'll fix that.

Comment: B::print won't use C::print either.

Comment: What method would you expect/want it to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's how C++ works -- once a function with a particular signature is marked as `virtual`, it's still `virtual` in every derived class, regardless of whether they explicitly use the keyword or not. My preference is to always use the extra (redundant) `virtual` to make it clear what's going on, but other people take the view that it's not needed so you may as well leave it out.

(However, an overload with a *different* signature will not automatically be virtual, and in fact will hide the base class method of the same name, unless a `using` directive is used to bring the base class definition into the derived scope.)

As to the reasoning, I don't think there's any particular language reason to forbid you "de-virtualising" a function. I guess Stroustrup decided in the early days to be forgiving of people forgetting `virtual` in a derived class, and getting unexpected behaviour as a result.

Comment: hardcore people also cheat a little bit and overload the `->` operator providing the so called "drill-down behaviour", that's another kind of polymorphism but I don't know how it could be practical or useful, usually a C++ compiler shows signs of bugs with this technique.

Comment: @user2485710 Eeek, that sounds a bit nasty. I've only ever seen `operator->` overloaded for smart pointers and iterators (which is reasonable as they're both acting as pointer-like things). Do you have any examples of this drill-down behaviour you can link to?

Comment: In case anyone cares: In C# you are force to choose between keeping the virtualisation (keyword override) or de-virtualising the function (keyword new). In Java, everything is always virtual anyway.

Comment: @user2485710: I've got no idea what you're suggesting, but I'm still fairly certain that "compiler bugs" are in fact cases of "Undefined Bheavior", i.e. not a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The language could work either way - it's a choice Stroustrup made:

- As is, it's easy to override select functions at various depths of derivation without re-listing all the un-overridden functions in every intervening class.  This reduces the maintenance burden as the code evolves, and when you look at a derived class it's emphasising what's actually changing or added with less clutter.
- If it worked as you seem to expect and you had to explicitly declare the virtual function again in `B`, then the compiler would expect an implementation, and the linker would fail without, so some new notation would be needed to indicate that you're only preserving the ability of further-derived classes to override the function but not intending to replace the base-class definition.  It all sounds a bit tedious and repetitive.

Defaulting to an ongoing ability to override virtual functions facilitates re-use, but for those relatively rare occasions when there's some boundary such as a corporate library API inside which some overriding is to be allowed but outside which modifications are being deliberately hampered, then in C++11 there's a `final` keyword that indicates derived classes aren't allowed to override the function: see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Answer (score 0):

It must. It's part of the contract expressed by the base class. If it wasn't propagated to derived classes it would be a violation of the tenets of OO, such as the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: In what sense would it violate LSP?

Comment: I disagree that it must. An alternative approach could be to require the user to provide the `virtual` keyword explicitly for derived classes. No violation of LSP would take place.